# Postman - Retrieve all values from Nested JSON in a list

Tags: json, postman

I am using Postman to run some APIs and get response. There is 1 API where I get the response:

```
{
        "Id": 412,
        "properties": {
            "instruction01": "RFI100044",
            "instruction02": "RFI100107",
            "instruction03": "RFI100127",
        }
 }
```

What I want:

1. Get values from all the attributes containing text "instruction" and put it in a list (which I will use later) **OR**
2. To get all the values(instruction01,instruction02..) from "properties" attribute and put it in a list and access from the list then.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
const res = pm.response.json();

let keys = Object.keys(res.properties);
let values = [];
keys.forEach((element) => {
    values.push(res.properties[element]);
});

console.log(values);
//["RFI100044", "RFI100107", "RFI100127"]
```